# How to make marker NOT centered in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a slinding up panel in an activity and i need the panel to be expanded on start, so when I do it it covers up the marker. How do I make the focus of the map be a little higher.

I tried the tilt provided in google map android documentation but it didn't work as I expected.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    LatLng temp = new LatLng(46.8182, 8.2275);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(temp, 8.0f));

}
```

I need the map to be a little higher. So the marker shouldn't be centered as many questions here ask. I need it to be NOT centered.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(temp)     // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                .zoom(13)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();
```